# Having confusion with branching in git

Tags: git, github

So, I have a branch checked out from the master branch.

**master**

- models

I have some changes in **models**. Now, I'm done with the work that I had to do in the **models** branch.

Similarly, I will create the next branch and do some work there and push to that branch itself.

So, what should I do next?

- Should I do this?

```
git pull origin models
git checkout master
git merge models
```

```
git pull origin nextBranch
git checkout master
git merge nextBranch
```

Now, it is being said, "Always stay up to date with the master". I don't understand what that means. We're not pushing anything to master, right? We're pushing to the local branches. Also, I've seen folks doing always `git pull origin master`. Can someone explain to me the proper workflow?
.

I don't know, I'm just confused.

Comment: I recommend *against* using `git pull`, for various reasons that are too long to go into in a comment. But note that it simply runs two Git commands: first it runs `git fetch` (which you, or anyone, can run at any time). Then it runs a second command that affects the *current branch*. You must first switch to the branch you want this second command to affect. You must also choose which second command to use: `git merge`, or `git rebase`. You must do this *before* you get a chance to see what `git fetch` does.

Comment: If you know for sure that the second command you want is always `git merge`, which is the default second command, then `git pull` is fine, but be sure you've first checked out whichever branch you want this `git pull` to affect.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you're new to Git, it's like a warehouse full of power tools, and you don't actually *know* which giant saw or drill press you want to use yet. It's not a fun situation and I think most Git introductory things do a pretty bad job of introducing Git. It's *hard* because, giant warehouse full of power tools. There is no way to get started in 5 minutes without being at risk of sawing off your thumbs.

Comment: Fortunately, there's a big set of DON'T PANIC words available too. That is: once you've *committed* something, the commits are usually pretty safe, so you can get them back. The big risk of sawing off thumbs, or whatever, comes from doing work without then using `git add` and `git commit`. If you've *committed* something, it's in there: it might not be trivial to get it back, but it can be gotten back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git pull origin master` tells git to update your current branch with whatever is currently in master. This is the command that you want to use regularly while working on your local branch to ensure you don't have any big merge conflicts to resolve when you are 'done' and ready to merge your code.

When you are done with the work on your feature branch (in this case called 'models'). It sounds like you want to merge that back into master, and push it

So, locally you would do

```
git checkout master
git merge models
git push
```

Which will switch you back to the master branch, merge the changes you had on the models branch into the master branch, then push those changes back to your central repository.

Comment: Will it be ```git push``` or ```git push origin master```?

Comment: `git push` will try and push the code to whatever remote you have configured for the branch you are currently on
`git push origin master` will try and push the code to the branch called 'master' of the remote labeled 'origin'

Usually, both of these things will result in the same action as the remote is configured when you preform your initial `git clone`

Answer (score 9):

I think the confusion comes from the different styles of working with git. Some of them are there because of personal preferences, and some because of a different workflow (working locally or with a remote for example, or using gitflow).

So, a little about the commands you asked about:

- `git pull origin master` - this will update the local master branch to be the same as the remote master branch. Assuming you're not working directly on your local master branch, this should always work and give you the latest changes available.
- `git pull origin <other_branch>` - Same as the previous bullet but for another branch. it fetches the remote copy of your local branch, merges the remote changes with your local changes, giving you the most up-to-date branch that includes your changes. Basically, it's like saving some of the work on the remote branch, making some local changes, and then creating a new document from both of the changes. You can force it to do a `rebase` instead of a merge by passing the flag `git pull --rebase origin master`

### Working Locally (without the cloud)

So basically, when you've finished working on a feature of a bug, you want to do the following:

- get and merge the latest saved changes for **the branch you want to merge** on origin (giving you all the changes) [`git pull origin models`]
- Move to the master branch [`git checkout master`]
- Merge the feature branch into the master branch (so that the feature will be part of the main branch) [`git merge models`]

**This will work as expected as long as you're working alone and don't plan to have someone else review your changes!**

### Working with other people

If you plan to work with other people, you probably want someone to go over your changes to make sure everything works as expected before merging the new feature to the master branch.

So you don't want to `git merge models` to your **local master branch**, but create a pull request on the remote git service and merge the **remote feature branch** with the **remote master branch** (after a code review). makes sense?

Here's the remote way of doing it (kind of simpler locally but with extra steps on the service itself):
**(Should be done on the feature branch)**

```
# get all the features that got merged into the master branch remotely (by other users) and merge them into your feature branch
git rebase origin/master
# get the latest changes (saved by you on a different machine) from the cloud and merge with local changes:
git pull origin models
# commit all the new changes locally
git add .
git commit
# push back to the cloud!
git push origin
```

Now on Github, you can create a pull request (you'll see a prompt to do that). After a code review, you can click on 'Merge Pull Request` to merge this branch to master.
[image]

you can see which branch you're going to merge into:
[image]